# NServiceBus.ObjectBuilder.Ninject critical bug

Tags: ninject, nservicebus

I'm experiencing [this error](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/12843) mentioned on the nsb group when running in the NServiceBus.Production profile.

Just wondering if it's a known issue (Remo ? :-) ) because it's currently going to prevent me using ninject with nsb.

NServiceBus.Ninject-CI.3.0.2044 nuget.

Many thanks!

```
2012-02-28 15:24:18,204 [Worker.8] WARN  NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.Transacti
onal.TransactionalTransport [(null)] <(null)> - Failed raising 'transport messag
e received' event for message with ID=02e57b0c-f345-46ae-a095-f52a4cfc0cfb\2071
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an obj
ect.
    at Ninject.Injection.DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.EmitMethodCall(ILGenerator
il, MethodInfo method) in c:\Projects\Ninject\Maintenance2.2\ninject\src\Ninject
\Injection\DynamicMethodInjectorFactory.cs:line 130
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't write the NSB ObjectBuilder for Ninject. From the exception I can tell that Ninject fails to inject a property because there is no public setter. With the an unchanged Ninject this cannot happen because these properties are filtered before unless Ninject is explicitly told that it shall not filter none public members.

I had a short look at the NinjectObjectBuilder. It adds new heuristic and it seems that it does not filter public properties with private setters. This implementation requires some change.

But I think this won't fix your problem since you want to have that property injected anyway. The proper way to do so is to change the setter to public. Alternatively, you can change the settings to allow privat member injection. `Settings.InjectNonPublic = true;` But I don't recommend to do that.

Comment: Thanks Remo, and thanks again for all your current work on ninject! I was hoping you'd know something about the NSB adapter, and this answer helps. Pete.